# How to add auto scroll inside bootstrap thumbnail class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails, autoscroll

I am creating a progress bars. I want to show the first three progress bar and hide the next  two, and i should be able to see subject 4 and subject 5 progress bar after scrolling that thumbnail.
Here is my JSFIDDLE [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/zL0tmqcm/) of HTML and CSS.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">                   
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img class="small-image" src="http://marccortez.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/reading-small1.jpg"/> 
        </div>
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="progress-broad">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:70%">
                </div> 
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning progress-bar-striped" style="width:10%">                                            
                </div>
                <span class="course-progressbar-name">Mathematics</span>
                <span class="course-grade-percentage">60%</span>
                <span class="course-grade-label">GRADE</span>     
            </div>
            <div class="progress-broad">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:70%">
                </div> 
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning progress-bar-striped" style="width:10%">                                            
                </div>
                <span class="course-progressbar-name">Biology</span>
                <span class="course-grade-percentage">60%</span>
                <span class="course-grade-label">GRADE</span>     
            </div>
            <div class="progress-broad">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:70%">
                </div> 
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning progress-bar-striped" style="width:10%">                                            
                </div>
                <span class="course-progressbar-name">Physics</span>
                <span class="course-grade-percentage">60%</span>
                <span class="course-grade-label">GRADE</span>     
            </div>
            <div class="progress-broad">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:70%">
                </div> 
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning progress-bar-striped" style="width:10%">                                            
                </div>
                <span class="course-progressbar-name">subject4</span>
                <span class="course-grade-percentage">60%</span>
                <span class="course-grade-label">GRADE</span>     
                </div>
            <div class="progress-broad">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:70%">
                </div> 
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning progress-bar-striped" style="width:10%">                                            
                </div>
                <span class="course-progressbar-name">subject5</span>
                <span class="course-grade-percentage">60%</span>
                <span class="course-grade-label">GRADE</span>     
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">                   
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img class="small-image" src="http://marccortez.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/reading-small1.jpg"/> 
        </div>
        <div class="thumbnail editor">
            <div class="progress-broad">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:70%">
                </div> 
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning progress-bar-striped" style="width:10%">                                            
                </div>
                <span class="course-progressbar-name">Mathematics</span>
                <span class="course-grade-percentage">60%</span>
                <span class="course-grade-label">GRADE</span>     
            </div>
            <div class="progress-broad">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:70%">
                </div> 
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning progress-bar-striped" style="width:10%">                                            
                </div>
                <span class="course-progressbar-name">Biology</span>
                <span class="course-grade-percentage">60%</span>
                <span class="course-grade-label">GRADE</span>     
            </div>
            <div class="progress-broad">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:70%">
                </div> 
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning progress-bar-striped" style="width:10%">                                            
                </div>
                <span class="course-progressbar-name">Physics</span>
                <span class="course-grade-percentage">60%</span>
                <span class="course-grade-label">GRADE</span>     
            </div>
            <div class="progress-broad">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:70%">
                </div> 
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning progress-bar-striped" style="width:10%">                                            
                </div>
                <span class="course-progressbar-name">subject4</span>
                <span class="course-grade-percentage">60%</span>
                <span class="course-grade-label">GRADE</span>     
                </div>
            <div class="progress-broad">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:70%">
                </div> 
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning progress-bar-striped" style="width:10%">                                            
                </div>
                <span class="course-progressbar-name">subject5</span>
                <span class="course-grade-percentage">60%</span>
                <span class="course-grade-label">GRADE</span>     
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

I added extra css:

```
.editor{
    height: 190px;
    overflow-y: visible;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
.progress-broad{
    position:relative;
}
```

[code here](http://jsfiddle.net/zL0tmqcm/2/%22overflow%22)